# Adding PolyLine in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to add a PolyLine. Why doesn't this work?

```
this.addLine = function(vertices)
{
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++)
    {
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(
        vertices[i].X, 
        vertices[i].Y, 
        vertices[i].Z));
    }

    var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({}));
    line.width = 199.9;

    scope.scene.add(line);
};
```

using it like this:

```
var objects = [
    { X: 216939.73,  Y: 6595308.75, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 216927.30,  Y: 6595310.31, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 216929.54,  Y: 6595328.01, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 216941.93,  Y: 6595326.46, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 216939.73,  Y: 6595308.75, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 209160.61,  Y: 6589441.50, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 209163.06,  Y: 6589460.77, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 209185.80,  Y: 6589457.87, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 209183.25,  Y: 6589438.52, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 209160.61,  Y: 6589441.50, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 220745.54,  Y: 6593881.96, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 220762.77,  Y: 6593892.37, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 220767.23,  Y: 6593885.00, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 220750.01,  Y: 6593874.55, Z: 547.92  },
    { X: 220745.54,  Y: 6593881.96, Z: 547.92  },
];

viewer.addLine(objects);
```

When I add lower points, like -10, 10, 0, it will render a line
near the grid, but while using real coordinates, it does not work. What's happening?

Comment: can you add initialization of your camera? your coordinates are huge numbers, are you sure your camera can see them?

Comment: Your camera just can't see it. Zoom out